# JS определить касаеться ли игрок(div) другого div

Tags: javascript, html

Я начал написание игры на js и html. У меня возник такой вопрос, у меня есть `<div id="player"></div>` и с помощью js генерируются так называемые персики, и дается кажому id к примеру:

```
<div id="peach1"></div>
<div id="peach2"></div>
```

А вот и сам вопрос как мне определять касается ли player, персика! При этом персиков может генерироваться от 5 до 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы сделаете свои `div` круглыми, то достаточно проверять условие

```
(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^ <= (r1 + r2)^2
```

где `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)` центры `div`, а `r1`, 'r2' - их радиусы

для прямоугольных `div` условия проверки гораздо сложнее, но если вы нарисуете все возможные случаи пересечения (их не так и много - 4 основных + довески), то поймете как можно сделать несколько проверок

для прямоугольных `div`, но развернутых под разными углами еще сложнее, но тут вам поможет решение частной задачи - нахождение точки пересечения отрезков (мы конечно про 2D говорим) - каждый `div` имеет 4 стороны, так что проверить придется 16 вариантов :)

но лучше пока вам первый способ использовать :)

Comment: Да, но у меня по сути размер тоже задается рандомно от 30-40, потом div там везде квадратные, и просто на bg через css задается изображение)